# Adding an item to a pop up list

Tags: design-patterns, multi-selection, drop-down-list

I have a form in which a user can select multiple tags via a pop-up window (multi-select with check boxes). The tags are maintained in admin/settings section. It is not a good experience if the user has to leave the form just to add a new tag. How can this be addressed? So far I have these options:

1) a button "add tag" in the pop-up. When the user clicks on the button the pop up window will show an area to enter a new tag text together with cancel & save.

2) In the form add a button "new tag" next to the "select tags" option. It would add a new tag but I think it is confusing to have select and new tag next to each other.

3) Use a new window for selecting tags instead of pop-up window. Then a new tag could be added via pop-up in this window.

Right now I would go with 1) but I don't really like any of these options. I have searched UX Stack Exchange but I have only found one similar question with one design option. Does anyone have different solutions?

**Update**

I came across this option. Adding something like this at the bottom of the list:
[image]

When some enters a new tag text and hits the plus sign then the new tag is added to the list with a check box (similar to gmail label structure) and this plus/new tag entry stays there for any additional entries.

Comment: see this solution from a similar question https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/127873/105958

Answer (score 2):

Gmail handles this in a very straight forward way.

When you select a message and ask to tag it, you are presented with a list of all existing tags:

[image]

If you select the "Create new" option you get a popup:

[image]

But if you just start typing in a label into the search that does not exist, you get the option to create it without the popup:

[image]

This last method is my personal preferred method of creating a new tag in Gmail.

Comment: This relates to the second option I mentioned in my question. The difference is that 'my labels' are in a pop up so that it cannot really open another pop up. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: @user3460486 - Having a second popup would indeed be a bad idea. You could simply not use the popup option in this example, instead just using the "create new" option when typing a tag that does not already exist.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was staring right back at you when you were typing the question and tagging it :). Did you check out the stack exchange tag question screen?

[image]

It's slick because it lets you select multiple tags by typing and clicking. It also lets you add a tag without leaving the screen.

Comment: I should have provided a mock up. The pop-up looks more like gmail labels. So there is no text box to enter text. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As thousandtyone and ECM mentioned, many tag controls, like the one on this site, simply allow the adding of a new tag unless you've picked one from the suggestions.

I'm particularly fond of way Jira handles it (slightly more usable than the SE way because it says '(New label)':

[image: The labels drop down on Jira - below the suggestion there's a line with the query string and new label in brackets]